# How to display search block in a modal dialog

Tags: 7, search, javascript

What I would like to accomplish is to display the search block in a modal dialog when the user clicks on a search button that I have created. I have created a search button block (basically an image with a link) and now I would like to point to the search block and have it appear in a modal dialog. I just don't know to go from here, or if it is even possible to go this route. Can someone provide some pointers on what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Lightbox or Colorbox (there are modules for both).

Each has the ability to display inline content in a modal.

All you would need to do is add your search block to the page and hide it with CSS, then adjust your search button link to trigger the lightbox/colorbox.

If using colorbox, you would do something like the following:

> Load content in a Colorbox
>
> Check the "Enable Colorbox load" option in Colorbox settings.
>
> This enables custom links that can open content in a Colorbox. Add the
>   class "colorbox-load" to the link and build the url like this
>   "[path]?width=500&height=500&iframe=true" or
>   "[path]?width=500&height=500" if you don't want an iframe.
>
> If you want to pass the width and height of the Colorbox as a
>   percentage (useful for responsive designs), you can format the link
>   like this "[path]?width=90%25&height=90%25&iframe=true" or
>   "[path]?width=90%25&height=90%25", where the "%25" is the HTML entity
>   for "%".
>
> Other modules may activate this for easy Colorbox integration.

Comment: I looked at the Colorbox module and noticed that it doesn't support forms anymore. They recommend using modal forms. Which is unfortunate as I am using Colorbox for other things.

Comment: I don't see any problem dropping the search block in one though, it doesn't have the complexity that normal forms have.  I just tested it using colorbox directly and it worked great: `var $form = $("#search-block-div");`
`$("#your-button").colorbox({inline:true, href:$form});`